# Alternativa para «mergear»

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática, neologismos

En mi trabajo no paro de escuchar el neologismo *mergear* para indicar que se ha hecho un *merge* de dos ramas en un repositorio de código, como Git (es decir, que el trabajo realizado en una rama se ha volcado en otra). No sé si este neologismo está extendido, una [búsqueda en Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mergear%22) apenas devuelve unos cuantos miles de resultados, lo cual está en el mismo orden de magnitud que los resultados de "[hacer un *merge*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hacer%20un%20merge%22)".

Sin embargo, estoy seguro de que debe de haber una palabra en español que se pueda usar para este concepto. Se me ocurren los verbos *[unir](https://dle.rae.es/unir)*, *[mezclar](https://dle.rae.es/mezclar)*, *[fusionar](https://dle.rae.es/fusionar)* y *[combinar](https://dle.rae.es/combinar)* y otros. La web del [IATE](https://iate.europa.eu/) parece que se decanta por *fusionar* (que daría el sustantivo *fusión* para *merge*), aunque no sé por qué a mí me suena haber visto *combinar* en algún sitio. Con todo, ¿cuál de todos los verbos posibles es el más usado en textos técnicos, webs profesionales y aplicaciones en español para este concepto?

Comment: Creo que está tan extendido que ya es tarde para buscarle alternativa. Y mira que suena raro dicho en la lengua propia :) Lo mismo estamos a tiempo de prevenir el uso de "commitear", "fetchear" y "merge request".

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' y de "castear" (hacer un "casting" de un tipo de objeto a otro), que también lo oigo por mis alrededores.

Comment: ¡Cierto! Se podría hacer un diccionario de la barbarie con lo que se llega a oír (o decir, que yo mismo lo hago).

Comment: En la traducción al castellano de la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-Básicos-para-Ramificar-y-Fusionar) de `Git`, usan la palabra (verbo) **fusionar**. Siendo `Git` uno de los sistemas de versión para desarrollo de software más ampliamente usados en la actualidad, creo que usar *fusionar* sería la alternativa adecuada.

Comment: En Canarias (al menos) usamos "mezclar" en el contexto de control de versiones

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Algunas traducciones de los sistemas de versión más usados en el ámbito del desarrollo de software hacen uso del verbo **fusionar**:

- En la traducción al castellano de la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-B%C3%A1sicos-para-Ramificar-y-Fusionar) de Git, usan la palabra (verbo) *fusionar*.
- Otro sistema de versiones es `Apache SubVersion (SVN)`, el cual es un proyecto bastante *antiguo*, y ofrece una versión en castellano de su [documentación](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/es/svn-ch-4.html) oficial. En dicha documentación también usan el verbo *fusionar*.
- Uno de los populares clientes para SVN: `Tortoise SVN`, también propone el uso del verbo *fusionar* en la traducción al castellano de su [documentación](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_es/tsvn-dug-merge.html).
- El popular repositorio de Internet `Github`, para manejo de versiones, también propone el uso del verbo *fusionar* como traducción a *merge* en su [documentación](https://docs.github.com/es/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository) oficial.

Me parece que la alternativa es **fusionar**, y aunque sólo he citado 4 fuentes relacionadas con el tema, lo difícil no es encontrar fuentes, sino motivar el uso de la alternativa antes que el neologismo.

Comment: ¡Entras por la puerta grande en [spanish.se]! Bienvenido, buena respuesta

Comment: En mi glosario proponía en 1997-02-01 las traducciones: intercalar, fusionar, unir, mezclar
Y como definición: Obtención de un único conjunto ordenado a partir de dos o más conjuntos ordenados según la misma regla.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que a comienzo de los años 70 (siglo pasado) se hablaba de 'sortear' un fichero, por clasificar, no por el bingo, creo que no me sorprende que se siga destrozando el idioma por no molestarse en abrir un diccionario. Nota. Yo estaba delante de más de una perla semejante mordiéndome los puños por no decir un inconveniente. Los novatos nos tragamos muchas cosas.